# Stress strain diagram for a spiral spring

Tags: material-science, stress-strain

I know that the stress strain diagram for steel looks like:

[image]

If this is experimentally determined usually a cylindrical piece of steel or a straight wire is used (from beginning of the experiment).

[image]

My question is: If you start the experiment with a real coil spring, how will the diagram look different? Do you have a reference for such an experiment starting with a real coil spring?

At the end, just before breaking it will just be a straight wire as well, but before reaching this point, the diagram might change a bit.

Answer (score 3):

A study of the mechanics of deforming a coil spring will reveal that each tiny cross-sectional element of the spring is being *twisted* as the spring is stretched i.e., the coil spring material is in a state of *torsion* instead of *tension*. In addition, because the coil spring loops are more or less at right angles to the direction of the pulling force, they are simultaneously in a state of *shear*.

Therefore, the elastic (linear) portion of the stress-strain curve of a coil spring measures the torsional and shear modulus of the material and not its tensile modulus.

Finally, note that the strains exhibited in response to the tensile stress imposed on the ends of the spring are distributed along a long length of the spring material rather than a short length of a straight tensile test specimen of the same diameter as the coil spring material. This means the coil spring will stretch much more than a tensile test specimen under the same stress meaning the slope of the stress-strain curve will be very shallow in comparison.